# Looking for comic about female superhero who loses her powers

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics

A while back, I read a comic (DC, I think) in a compilation that I'd like to find again.  I think it was one issue.  Even though this character could have more comics, I'm just looking for the one issue.  This was ages ago, so my details are very fuzzy.

The story starts with a girl with long black hair in her bedroom with a friend.  Her friend jumps on the bed, and the girl flies around it.  I think they discuss how she gained superpowers.  She has a yellow star she wears on her chest that gives her her powers.  I think her superhero costume is red with yellow.  To the best of my memory, I think it's Batman who introduces her to the superhero world.  Her mom knows about this.  The girl ends up getting shot or something, and the yellow star shatters.  Her mom is later crying over a scrapbook, saying how sad everything is.  The girl says "It's not like I died or anything Mom - I just don't have powers anymore."  She goes to her room, her hair in a towel, and sees her superhero costume on her bed with a note from Batman.  She smiles and looks out the window, and I think there's a silhouette of Batman.

Comment: Was I the only one who saw the title and immediately thought of Empowered, whose titular superheroine regularly loses her powers as a result of her costume being damaged?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### All-Star.

In the DCAU follow up comics we [encounter](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Justice_League_Adventures_Vol_1_13) Olivia Dawson (AKA [All-Star](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Olivia_Dawson_(DCAU))). 
She wields the [Star Charm](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Charm), a device of Qwardian weaponsmiths.

[image]

[image]

She was only a hero for a very short time before she sacrificed the charm to defeat Brainiac and fake her own 'death'.

[image]

Comment: OP might be interested to know that (according to the DC fandom wik)i, she was introduced in Justice League Adventures (Volume 1) #13.  Cover date January 2003. https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Justice_League_Adventures_Vol_1_13

Comment: YES!  Thank you so much; it's amazing to finally find it!  And thank you msouth for the link!  I greatly appreciate it!